# Getting current object data in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects.

Ex:

```
 data=[
  {
    name: 'Person1',
    age: 30,
    weight: 200
  },
  {
    name: 'Person2',
    age: 30,
    weight: 200
  },
  {
    name: 'Person3',
    age: 30,
    weight: 200
  }
]
```

I am mapping through the array and returning only the Person and age.

How can i get the full object data when I click on that person.

For example I am rendering the below.

I would like to console.log ALL the objects properties for the specific one I click.

I am trying to simplify this, I hope its not confusing.

```
 return(
    //This is a function that is mapping through the objects and printing out each objects Name and age only
    this.loopData()  
    )



 loopData = ()=>{
    return data.map(obj,i) =>{
    return(<h1 onClick={this.showme} key={i}>{obj.name}</h1>}
    }
```

I have the onlick as
showme =() =>console.log(this)

If the info is there, under what label would I be looking for?

Comment: Your array is not *valid*.

Comment: It was an example, but I will fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  On calling the below functional component renders a button with person name. Onclicking the person will log it in console

    const renderPerson = () => {
      let data=[
        {
          name: 'Person1',
          age: 30,
          weight: 200
        },
        {
          name: 'Person2',
          age: 30,
          weight: 200
        },
        {
          name: 'Person3',
          age: 30,
          weight: 200
        }
      ]


      return(
        <div>
          {data.map(person => (
             <button onClick={() => console.log(JSON.stringify(person))}>person.name</button>       
          ))}
        </div>
      )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access object properties by a string value you can do:

```
var data = {
 Person1: {
  age: 22,
  weight: 180
 }
};

var _clickedid = "Person1";
var _clickedobj = data[_clickedid];
console.log(_clickedobj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) you can get the `person` with name `'Person1'` and age `30`

Code:

```js
const data = [{name: 'Person1',age: 30,weight: 200},{name: 'Person2',age: 30,weight: 200},{name: 'Person3',age: 30,weight: 200}];
const person = data.find(p => p.name === 'Person1' && p.age === 30);

console.log(person);
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you are trying to achieve something like this, but I might be mistaken.

```js
const data = [
    {
      name: 'Person1',
      age:30,
      weight:200
    },
    {
      name: 'Person2',
      age:20,
      weight:180
    },
    {
      name: 'Person3',
      age:10,
      weight:100
    }
]

const generateHtml = data => {
  const list = document.createElement('ul');
  document.body.appendChild(list);

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let item = document.createElement('li');
    item.textContent = data[i].name;
    list.appendChild(item)

    item.addEventListener('click', event => {
      console.log(data[i]);
    });
  }
}

generateHtml(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should bind the person in the map loop to be able to get clicked person in you click handler function.

```
showPerson(person) {
  // do stuff 
  console.log(JSON.stringify(person))
}

render() {
  let data = [
    {
      name: 'Person1',
      age: 30,
      weight: 200
    },
    {
      name: 'Person2',
      age: 30,
      weight: 200
    },
    {
      name: 'Person3',
      age: 30,
      weight: 200
    }
  ];

  return(
    <div>
      {
        data.map(person => (
          <button
            onClick={this.showPerson.bind(null, person)}>
            person.name
          </button>       
        ))
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```